# Apostrophe in memo text causing error in code

Tags: sql, vba, apostrophe

I am using Access 2016 and I am running into an error where a memo field gets updated and people are using apostrophes and it interferes with the code to update.  The code works great and it updates the table for specific values unless there is an apostrophe present.  No amount of parentheses or brackets have resolved this issue to isolate the apostrophes in text from the code.  I would prefer suggestions that would I allow me to have apoostrophes if possible.

```
Private Sub btnlledit_Click()
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "UPDATE tblll " & _
      "SET [LLN] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtlln & "',[REF] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllref & "',[TRN] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtlltr & "',[HN] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllhull & "', [LL] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtll & "',[CA] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllca & "',[CP] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllcomponent & "',[LOC] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllloc & "',[LFSE] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtlllfse & "',[FC] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllfc & "' " & _
      "WHERE [LLN] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtlln.Value & "';"


DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
DoCmd.Requery

Me.Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: Use parameters. That not only prevents SQL injection attacks but solves problems like this right from the start. As a good measure, never write SQL Statements like this with string concatenation.

Comment: I am very new to programming in general, what do you mean by use parameters?

Comment: I will add that as an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I've cut down your SQL to give you an idea.

The first line of SQL are the parameters - note the `;` at the end of the first line.

```
Private Sub btnlledit_Click()

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS  LLN_Value TEXT(255), REF_Value TEXT(255), TRN_Value TEXT(255); " & _
        "UPDATE tblll " & _
        "SET LLN = LLN_Value, REF = REF_Value, TRN = TRN_Value " & _
        "WHERE LLN = LLN_Value")

    With qdf
        .Parameters("LLN_Value") = Forms!frmaddll!txtlln
        .Parameters("REF_Value") = Forms!frmaddll!txtllref
        .Parameters("TRN_Value") = Forms!frmaddll!txtlltr
        .Execute
    End With

End Sub
```

A better way would be to move the execution of the query to another procedure and pass the required values to that:

```
Public Sub MyQuery(My_LLN_Value AS String, My_Ref_Value AS String, My_TRN_Value AS String)

    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS  LLN_Value TEXT(255), REF_Value TEXT(255), TRN_Value TEXT(255); " & _
        "UPDATE tblll " & _
        "SET LLN = LLN_Value, REF = REF_Value, TRN = TRN_Value " & _
        "WHERE LLN = LLN_Value")

    With qdf
        .Parameters("LLN_Value") = My_LLN_Value
        .Parameters("REF_Value") = My_Ref_Value
        .Parameters("TRN_Value") = My_TRN_Value
        .Execute
    End With

End Sub
```

You can then call this procedure from your button click:

```
Private Sub btnlledit_Click()

    MyQuery Forms!frmaddll!txtlln, Forms!frmaddll!txtllref, Forms!frmaddll!txtlltr

End Sub
```

Or from elsewhere, and getting your values from elsewhere to:

```
Public Sub Test

    Dim Second_Arg AS String
    Second_Arg = "Some Reference Value"

    MyQuery Forms!frmaddll!txtlln, Second_Arg, "Third Argument"

End Sub
```

Comment: I copied and pasted the first one into access to just try and start the code to make sure I could run it, when I click edit with the parameters as defined those 3 values do not produce an update when altered and edited.  Do I need to alter it more?   I will probably use the suggested split once I can get a better hang of setting parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _when I click edit with the parameters as defined those 3 values do not produce an update when altered and edited_.  What did you click _edit_ on?  I guess the first thing to ask is - are all the parameters meant to be text fields?  The most likely data types for parameters would be:  Text Strings - **TEXT(255)**, Yes/No(Boolean) - **Bit**, Dates - **DateTime**, Long Integers - **Long**, Double values - **Double**.  Do your form references return values correctly?

Comment: Also as @CetinBasoz said - you're setting the value of LLN while limiting the returned results to that value.  This could be a reason for no results being returned - if your table doesn't contain LLN values matching `Forms!frmaddll!txtlln` before the update then it won't be able to update anything.

Comment: Click edit is the button that is clicked to run everything, Everything is text fields, but not all the limits are 255 charaters. The form references are correct.  I was in a meeting I am going to look at the code a little more and see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I said in a minute but had other stuff (+ writing this in VBA is a torture):

```
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "UPDATE tblll " & _
      "SET [REF] = @ref,[TRN] = @trn,[HN] = @hn" & _
      ", [LL] = @ll,[CA] = @ca,[CP] = @cp,[LOC] = @loc " & _
      ", [LFSE] = @lfse, [FC] = @fc" & _
      "WHERE [LLN] = @lln";"

   Dim oConnection As ADODB.Connection
   Dim oCommand As ADODB.Command

  Set oConnection = New ADODB.Connection
  Set oCommand = New ADODB.Command

  oConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\MyFolder\MyData.accdb;"

  oConnection.Open
  oCommand.ActiveConnection = oConnection
  oCommand.CommandText = SQL


  oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("@ref", adInteger)
  oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("@trn", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100)
  oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("@hn", adInteger)
  oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("@ll", adInteger)
  oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("@ca", adInteger)
  oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("@cp", adInteger)
  oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("@loc", adInteger)
  oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("@lfse", adInteger)
  oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("@fc", adInteger)
  oCommand.Parameters.Append oCommand.CreateParameter("@lln", adInteger)

  oCommand.Parameters("@ref" ).Value = Forms!frmaddll!txtref.Value
  oCommand.Parameters("@trn" ).Value = Forms!frmaddll!txttrn.Value
  oCommand.Parameters("@hn"  ).Value = Forms!frmaddll!txthn.Value
  oCommand.Parameters("@ll"  ).Value = Forms!frmaddll!txtll.Value
  oCommand.Parameters("@ca"  ).Value = Forms!frmaddll!txtca.Value
  oCommand.Parameters("@cp"  ).Value = Forms!frmaddll!txtcp.Value
  oCommand.Parameters("@loc" ).Value = Forms!frmaddll!txtloc.Value
  oCommand.Parameters("@lfse").Value = Forms!frmaddll!txtlfse.Value
  oCommand.Parameters("@fc"  ).Value = Forms!frmaddll!txtfc.Value
  oCommand.Parameters("@lln" ).Value = Forms!frmaddll!txtlln.Value

  oCmd.Execute
```

This code is not specifically an access code but VBA (that you can execute from any VBA environment, say Excel, Word ...).
Since I don't know your fields, parameter types are just for sampling. The important thing here is, you have to define the parameters in the same order as they appear in your query string. After appending the parameters, you are free to set their values in any order you like (that is a limitation in driver I think, parameters are not named but positional).

NOTE: I dropped initial LLN= because you were searching for it and setting to the same value (IOW no change).

Comment: My access is being weird here and not letting me use ADODB.  I might have to make a new db and transfer this over to run it because of the restrictions on the current DB.  I'll let you know in a little how this is turning out.

Comment: @Kewl147, you might need to add ADODB from references (Microsoft.ActiveXDataObjects). Or better, do yourself a favor and use a real database (and a language other than VBA).

Comment: I figured that out I had to remove and add a few things from the references, however now I am getting an error saying that the file is currently in use or placed in state by an admin.  I am currently configuring settings.

Answer (score 0):

**Single quotes are escaped by doubling them up**, just as you've shown us in your example. The following SQL illustrates this functionality.

BTW, Go for SQL Parameter instead of these inline SQL Injection.

Try like below:

```
Private Sub btnlledit_Click()
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "UPDATE tblll " & _
          "SET [LLN] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtlln & "',[REF] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllref & "',[TRN] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtlltr & "',[HN] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllhull & "', [LL] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtll & "',[CA] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllca & "',[CP] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllcomponent & "',[LOC] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllloc & "',[LFSE] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtlllfse & "',[FC] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtllfc & "' " & _
          "WHERE [LLN] = '" & Forms!frmaddll!txtlln.Value & "';"

    Replace (SQL, "'", "''")

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
    DoCmd.Requery

    Me.Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: I have provide example only with his sample. Also, i have advised him to go for Parameter. @Fredou

Comment: if I put in the code directly as you have it (SQL=SQL.replace...) it receives an error say invalid qualified and highlights the SQL portion of SQL.replace.  If I remove the SQL from replace then I get a syntax error for the update.

Comment: @Kewl147 Try it now

Comment: VBA with SQL in sequence when I can use it.

Comment: It's recieving a syntax error, I've tried setting it as a seperate string and as a preface before the initial line of code.  One of the times when I set it it said I had an invalid operator = .  I am still rearranging.